# Testing if button changes state, or if component appears (React)

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a component with a button and a form. When button is visible, the form is hidden and the opposite - when we click button it dissapears and form is shown. I would like to test it either with enzyme or testing-library, but all my tests fail.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';

const FormComponent = () => {
  const [isFormVisible, setFormVisibility] = useState(false);

  function toggleFormVisibility() {
    setFormVisibility(!isFormVisible);
  }
  return (
    <section>
      {!isFormVisible && (
        <button
          id='toggle-form-button'
          data-testid='toggle-form-button'
          onClick={toggleFormVisibility}
        >
          Show form
        </button>
      )}
    {isFormVisible && <Form onCancel={toggleFormVisibility} />}
    </section>
  );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

My test:

```
describe('Form component', () => {
  it('should fire toggle form action on button click', () => {
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
    useStateSpy.mockImplementation(() => [undefined, setState]);

    const component = render(
      <Form />
    );
    const showFormButton = component.getByTestId('toggle-form-button');
    Simulate.click(showFormButton);
    expect(showFormButton).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

and another one:

```
  it('should fire toggle form action on button click', () => {
    const toggleFormVisibility = jest.fn();

    const component = render(
      <Form />
    );
    const showFormButton = component.getByTestId('toggle-form-button');
    Simulate.click(showFormButton);
    expect(toggleFormVisibility).toBeCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your tests, you are trying to render the `<Form>` instead of the `<FormComponent>`, that might be causing the problem in your test.

Also in your 2nd test, you are not setting up the `toggleFormVisibility` mocked function with your component, so that wouldn't be invoked at all, the answer above is pretty reasonable, you might want to consider giving that a shot, not sure why it gets downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

testing-library may make this test easier:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

render(<Form />);
fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('Show form'));
```

Comment: I get error Property 'setFormVisibility' does not exist on type 'RenderResult<typeof import("/..................../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/typings/queries")>'.